# Select first word - mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

i need to select only the **first name** (that is the first word) of the user.

For example, Andy Jones, only select Andy

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

```
select substring_index(field, " ", 1) ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, your FirstName and LastName are in one column. You can achieve this using [user defined functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html).

**Example:**

`SELECT SPLIT_STR(name, ' ', 1) as firstname FROM   users;`

Read following post for more options:

- [Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/mysql-split-value-from-one-field-to-two)

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you would normally put the first and last name in their own columns.  If you cannot, then you can get the index of the first space, then substring(0,index of the first space).  I would really recommend though that you split that into two columns, if you can.