# Split column string into multiple columns strings

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I have a entry in the table that is a string which is delimited by semicolons. Is possible to split the string into separate columns? I've been looking online and at stackoverflow and I couldn't find one that would do the splitting into columns.

The entry in the table looks something like this (anything in brackets [] is not actually in my table. Just there to make things clearer):

```
sysinfo [column]
miscInfo ; vendor: aaa ; bootr: bbb; revision: ccc; model: ddd [string a]
miscInfo ; vendor: aaa ; bootr: bbb; revision: ccc; model: ddd [string b]
...
```

There are a little over one million entries with the string that looks like this. Is it possible in mySQL so that the query returns the following

```
  miscInfo,   Vendor,   Bootr,  Revision ,  Model [columns]
miscInfo_a, vendor_a,  bootr_a, revision_a, model_a
miscInfo_b, vendor_b,  bootr_b, revision_b, model_b
...
```

for all of the rows in the table, where the comma indicates a new column?

**Edit:**

Here's some input and output as Bohemian requested.

```
sysinfo [column]
Modem <<HW_REV: 04; VENDOR: Arris ; BOOTR: 6.xx; SW_REV: 5.2.xxC; MODEL: TM602G>>

<<HW_REV: 1; VENDOR: Motorola ; BOOTR: 216; SW_REV: 2.4.1.5; MODEL: SB5101>>

Thomson DOCSIS Cable Modem <<HW_REV: 4.0; VENDOR: Thomson; BOOTR: 2.1.6d; SW_REV: ST52.01.02; MODEL: DCM425>>
```

Some can be longer entries but they all have similar format. Here is what I would like the output to be:

```
miscInfo, vendor, bootr, revision, model [columns]
    04,   Arris,  6.xx, 5.2.xxC, TM602G
    1, Motorola, 216, 2.4.1.5, SB5101
  4.0, Thomson, 2.1.6d, ST52.01.02, DCM425
```

Comment: FYI, it's "thanks in advance". No trailing "d". That seems to be a very popular error.

Comment: "thanksd"? Anyway, OP: Make sure your data model is normalised, and don't reimplement your own pet database inside a database column.

Comment: Could you please show *exact* input and *exact* expected output? For example, does `vendor: aaa` really become `vendor_a`?

Comment: @Bohemian, I updated my original post to include 3 actual entries in my DB and what I would like the result to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of String functions (particularly **substr**) in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Substr requires start and end index. The problem with this is that the ';' is not always in the same index in the string. For an example see my edit above. The first column should explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at how I've split my coordinates column into 2 lat/lng columns:

```
UPDATE shops_locations L 
LEFT JOIN shops_locations L2 ON L2.id = L.id
SET L.coord_lat = SUBSTRING(L2.coordinates, 1, LOCATE('|', L2.coordinates) - 1), 
L.coord_lng = SUBSTRING(L2.coordinates, LOCATE('|', L2.coordinates) + 1)
```

In overall I followed `UPDATE JOIN` advice from here [MySQL - UPDATE query based on SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query) and `STR_SPLIT` question here [Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/mysql-split-value-from-one-field-to-two)

Yes I'm just splitting into 2, and SUBSTRING might not work well for you, but anyway, hope this helps :)