# SQL SELECT everything after a certain character

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, string-length

I need to extract everything after the last '=' (http://www.domain.com?query=blablabla - > blablabla) but this query returns the entire strings. Where did I go wrong in here:

```
SELECT RIGHT(supplier_reference, CHAR_LENGTH(supplier_reference) - SUBSTRING('=', supplier_reference)) 
FROM ps_product
```

Comment: What database engine are you using? It's not SQL Server, right?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422739/2713729

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(supplier_reference,'=',-1) from ps_product;
```

Please use [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for further reference.

Comment: That can cause some problems, it there's no '=' in the column, in that case you can use: `SELECT IF(LOCATE('=', supplier_reference), SUBSTRING_INDEX(supplier_reference,'=',-1), default_value) FROM ps_product;` and you can set a default value instead returning the original full column.

Comment: What if string contains multiple '=' and I want everything after first '='?

Comment: This is not entirely correct. To be able to set the right negative index you need to know exactly how many times the searched string occurs in the subject. For that this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12344881/2713729

Answer (score 9):

Try this (it should work if there are multiple '=' characters in the string):

```
SELECT RIGHT(supplier_reference, (CHARINDEX('=',REVERSE(supplier_reference),0))-1) FROM ps_product
```

Comment: CHARINDEX doesn't exist in MySQL which the question was about. The MySQL alternative is LOCATE.

Answer (score 8):

In MySQL, this works if there are multiple '=' characters in the string

```
SUBSTRING(supplier_reference FROM (LOCATE('=',supplier_reference)+1))
```

It returns the substring after(+1) having found the the first =

Comment: This was useful when there are multiple '=' and we want string after first occurrence of '='

Answer (score 7):

Try this in MySQL.

```
right(field,((CHAR_LENGTH(field))-(InStr(field,','))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It would be more helpful to add some explanation of how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your string is

```
str = 'abc=def=ghi'
```

To select to the right:

```
select substring_index(str,'=',-1) from tablename ==> result is 'ghi'
select substring_index(str,'=',-2) from tablename ==> result is 'def=ghi'
```

To select to the left

```
select substring_index(str,'=',-1) from tablename ==> result is 'abc'

select substring_index(str,'=',2) from tablename ==> result is 'abc=def'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on something similar and after a few tries and fails came up with this:

Example:
**STRING-TO-TEST-ON = 'ab,cd,ef,gh'**

I wanted to extract everything after the last occurrence of "," (comma) from the string... resulting in "gh".

**My query is:**

```
SELECT SUBSTR('ab,cd,ef,gh' FROM (LENGTH('ab,cd,ef,gh') - (LOCATE(",",REVERSE('ab,cd,ef,gh'))-1)+1)) AS `wantedString`
```

Now let me try and explain what I did ...

1. I had to find the position of the last "," from the string and to calculate the wantedString length, using `LOCATE(",",REVERSE('ab,cd,ef,gh'))-1` by reversing the initial string I actually had to find the first occurrence of the "," in the string ... which wasn't hard to do ... and then -1 to actually find the string length without the ",".
2. calculate the position of my wantedString by subtracting the string length I've calculated at 1st step from the initial string length:

   LENGTH('ab,cd,ef,gh') - (LOCATE(",",REVERSE('ab,cd,ef,gh'))-1)+1

I have (+1) because I actually need the string position after the last "," .. and not containing the ",". Hope it makes sense.

3. all it remain to do is running a SUBSTR on my initial string FROM the calculated position.

**I haven't tested the query on large strings so I do not know how slow it is. So if someone actually tests it on a large string I would very happy to know the results.**

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Management studio I used a variation of BWS' answer. This gets the data to the right of '=', or NULL if the symbol doesn't exist:

```
   CASE WHEN (RIGHT(supplier_reference, CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('=',supplier_reference,0)) = 0 THEN
    0 ELSE CHARINDEX('=', supplier_reference) -1 END)) <> '' THEN (RIGHT(supplier_reference, CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('=',supplier_reference,0)) = 0 THEN
    0 ELSE CHARINDEX('=', supplier_reference) -1 END)) ELSE NULL END
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '=', -1), column)
```