# MYSQL : Find the last occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: mysql, string

> Length will be dynamic and i want to find the data before last occurrence of a character in a string in MYSQL

Like **strrchr** in php

> To get last occurrence of _ (underscore) I need to pass length. and here it's 3

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX ('this_is_something_here', '_', 3);

+----------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX ('this_is_something_here', '_', 3) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| this_is_something                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

> And here, to get last occurrence of _ (underscore) i need to pass length. and here it's 6

```
 

mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX ('and_this_may_go_like_this_too', '_', 6);
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX ('and_this_may_go_like_this_too', '_', 6) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| and_this_may_go_like_this                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

> i want data string before last  occurrence of _ (underscore) just shown in above example but without passing length.
>
> Note : from above example i want before data of "_here" and "_too"
>
> last occurrence of _ (underscore)

Is there any built-in functionality to achieve this in MySQL?

Thanks in advance amigos.

Comment: you want to find 'here' and 'too' above ?

Comment: No, i want before data of "here" and "too"

Comment: this and something ?

Comment: From example 1 : this_is_something

Comment: and from example 2 : and_this_may_go_like_this

Comment: you want to do that without passing length static or don't want to pass dynamic length

Comment: answer this query also ?

Comment: Yes, just want the **before** data string of last occurrence of _ (underscore)

Comment: no if we do above query with dynamic length then ? you said "i want data string before last occurrence of _ (underscore) just shown in above example but without passing length."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last index of a given substring in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775352/last-index-of-a-given-substring-in-mysql)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I didn't quite get your examples, but I think what you want is to pass -1 as the length and prepend the substring prior.

Compare

```
strrchr('and_this_may_go_like_this_too', '_'); // Returns _too

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('and_this_may_go_like_this_too', '_', -1);
-- Returns too, just need to concatenate `_` so...
SELECT CONCAT('_', SUBSTRING_INDEX('and_this_may_go_like_this_too', '_', -1));
-- Returns _too
```

If you're looking for the part of the string *before* and up to the needle, and **not** from the needle to the end of the string, you can use:

```
SET @FULL_STRING = 'this_is_something_here';  

SELECT LEFT(@FULL_STRING, LENGTH(@FULL_STRING) - LOCATE('_', REVERSE(@FULL_STRING)));
-- Returns this_is_something
```

Note that the second statement is **not** what `strrchr` does.

Comment: i want data string before last occurrence of _ (underscore) just shown in above example but without passing length.

Comment: From example 1 : **this_is_something** without passing the length

Comment: That's not quite `strrchr` then (as that returns the matched occurrence till the end of the string), do you mind updating the question?

Comment: Actually bro it is :) it returns the portion of haystack which starts at the last occurrence of needle and goes until the end of haystack.

Comment: what server side language you are using ? @AdityaShah

Comment: php but i want solution in mysql :) @Gaurav

Comment: @AdityaShah Your output is from the start of the string to the last occurrence of the substring. That's different. If you're looking for that, the SQL would be `SET @FULL_STRING = 'this_is_something_here'; SELECT LEFT(@FULL_STRING, LENGTH(@FULL_STRING) - LOCATE('_', REVERSE(@FULL_STRING)));` but that is again, not `strrchr`.

Comment: @AlvinTeh it's works fine :) but don't we have any SQL function for that ?

Comment: Because i can't pass this in sql, it's large dynamic query and above is just small part of that.

Comment: @AdityaShah I'm not aware of any single MySQL function that would achieve that. A quick search revealed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference) which seems to match my guess. If the SQL query is large, consider using stored procedures or user functions instead.

Comment: You can check my answer

Comment: @maSTAShuFu You're using more than one function as well. @AdityaShah just in case it's not obvious, you don't *absolutely* have to use variables, you can always just substitute `@FULL_STRING` in my code with the actual string.

Comment: That's only a test to substitute the column... more functions but no length as per requirement

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I think the OP wanted to achieve this with just one function; I did the same earlier (see the earlier comments in this thread).

Comment: That's ridiculous... then create a scalar function which contains our scripts haha

Comment: Yeah @AlvinTeh exactly with one function

Answer (score 2):

```
select reverse(substr(reverse('this_is_something_here'), 1+locate('_', reverse('this_is_something_here'))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use reverse, locate, right then replace without using length

```
Set @str = 'there_is_something';

Select replace(@str,right(@str,locate('_',reverse(@str))),'');
```

Comment: Yo dog, I heard OP likes just one function... so I put your functions in just one function.  `CREATE FUNCTION just_one_function(_in LONGTEXT) RETURNS LONGTEXT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL RETURN REPLACE(_in,RIGHT(_in,LOCATE('_',REVERSE(_in))),'');`

Comment: `SELECT just_one_function('this_works_well');` → `this_works`

Comment: Yup like what i said from the other answer. OP is not complete

Answer (score 1):

You can write query like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('and_this_may_go_like_this_too','_',(LENGTH('and_this_may_go_like_this_too')-LENGTH(REPLACE('and_this_may_go_like_this_too' ,'_',''))) - 1);
```