# Sorting values in ascending order based on number and year in MySQL. The oldest year and smallest number value means the record shows up first in asc

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to sort a MySQL table data based on a column values.

| id | record_number | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ent/4/2022 | 2022-10-24 20:34:25 | 2022-10-24 20:34:25 |
| 3 | ent/6/2021 | 2022-10-24 20:35:03 | 2022-10-24 20:35:03 |

The column is named `record_number` and the values of column follow the format `ent/4/2022`, where `ent` is common in all entries and `4` is the record number and `2022` is the year the record was created.

How can I sort the records in a MySQL query such that an entry like `ent/6/2021` shows up before `ent/4/2022` when displaying the sorting results in ascending order?

The sorting result in descending order should look something like this.

| id | record_number | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ent/4/2022 | 2022-10-24 20:34:25 | 2022-10-24 20:34:25 |
| 3 | ent/6/2021 | 2022-10-24 20:35:03 | 2022-10-24 20:35:03 |

This implies the record `id` = `1` is newer compared to record with `id` = `3` because it was created in 2021 and the latter in 2022.

Comment: Please [edit] you question to include (as text) sample data and the desired result. Also indicate data types of your columns.

Comment: @PM77-1 edited to add sample data. The `record_number` column is of ` text` data type.

Comment: Can you please add an additional row for each year?  Need to understand the sorting within the same record year.

Comment: @ErgestBasha 4 is a number not a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
  1*RIGHT(record_number, 4), /* extracts the year (assumes a 4-digit year) */
  1*SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(record_number, '/', 2), 5 ) /* extracts record number */
```

`1*` converts the extracted strings into `INT` so they can be sorted numerically rather than alphabetically.

If years won't always be 4 digits, use:

```
ORDER BY
  1*RIGHT(record_number, LOCATE('/', REVERSE(record_number))-1),
  1*SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(record_number, '/', 2), 5 )
```

[MYSQL : Find the last occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276940/mysql-find-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
select * 
from test
order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(record_number,'/',-2),'/',+1) *1  asc,
         str_to_date(replace(record_number,'ent','00'),'%d/%m/%Y') desc;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/nUOCNgy_

First you need to disable [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) then  replace ent with 00 and use str_to_date to form a date column .

The line `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(record_number,'/',-2),'/',+1) *1  asc` will get only the charchters between `/ /` and cast it to number