# MySQL Extract Postcode From Address Field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `address` column in my table that stores addresses in the following format `Street Name, Town Name, Postcode`. I know that I can use the `explode` function in PHP and get the postcode based on the commas. My question is, is there a way to extract the postcode using through a query?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data so we can see what the `address` looks like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last index of a given substring in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775352/last-index-of-a-given-substring-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your components are separated by commas an always have a postcode, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(address, ',', -1) as postcode
```

Comment: Beautiful! Lovely little snippet