# mysql splitting a field into one more table with related fields os other table

Tags: mysql

I am new to this group. I have one doubt in mysql query. hope anybody will give the right solution.

i want to split some values from one field and want to check in other table. hope you are not clear.

For example,

## TABLE1

```
id primarySkill

1 : 2318, 5236, 8541
2 : 5236,8762
3 : 8541, 2318, 5236, 8762
```

## TABLE2

```
id value

2318 java
5236 php
8541 .net
8762 Photoshop
```

## i want TABLE1 ouput like this:

```
id primarySkill
1 : java,php, .net
2 : php, Photoshop
3 : .net, java,php, Photoshop
```

how to write query for this? your swift action shall be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a ton of answers on SO for splitting a string.  Here's a highly-rated one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/mysql-split-value-from-one-field-to-two