# Split a String every 5 characters and get distinct strings

Tags: mysql, split

So I have a column with strings that are multiples of 5 characters, such as "12345" or "abcde12345" or "asdfghjkli12345". What I'm trying to do is write a query to split each of these strings into 5 character chunks and return the distinct ones.

So with "12345" , "abcde12345" , "asdfghjkli12345"

I would get back "12345" "abcde" "asdfg" and "hjkli"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not include a function to split a delimited string. Although separated data would normally be split into separate fields within a relation data, spliting such can be useful either during initial data load/validation or where such data is held in a text field.

The following formula can be used to extract the Nth item in a delimited list, in this case the 3rd item "ccccc" in the example comma separated list.

select replace(substring(substring_index('aaa,bbbb,ccccc', ',', 3), length(substring_index('aaa,bbbb,ccccc', ',', 3 - 1)) + 1), ',', '') ITEM3

The above formula does not need the first item to be handled as a special case and returns empty strings correctly when the item count is less than the position requested.

You can also create your own split function and use it. [Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/mysql-split-value-from-one-field-to-two)

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like it would be outside the limitations of SQL and would certainly require a programming language. It would be VERY easy in any 3GL.