# get text after some symbol in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need mysql query which brings the text after **(e)** symbol

eg. I have the following text in mysql table

```
test of my application (e) I'm so happy
```

after run query I need as a result `I'm so happy`

Comment: Check out [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/mysql-split-value-from-one-field-to-two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly easy with [`substring_index()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column_name`, ')', -1) // return everything from the right of the closing parentheses
```