# Is there a way to separate a column into two?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to separate a column into two ?

The column its like this

```
BRAND/PRODUCT
```

And I wanted to insert them into 2 new columns BRAND and PRODUCT

Thanks

Comment: Is there a \ between the values for BRAND and PRODUCT in every row of the table?

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/mysql-split-value-from-one-field-to-two

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `LOCATE` to find the `/`, and `SUBSTR` to grab the parts of the string before and after it.

```
UPDATE table
SET brand = SUBSTR(brand_product, 1, LOCATE('/', brand_product)-1),
    product = SUBSTR(brand_product, LOCATE('/', brand_product)+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially splits the field value. The "1" in the first one gets the first text segment, the "-1" in the second one gets the last text segment.

```
UPDATE `table` 
  SET `brand`   = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`brand_product`, '/', 1), 
      `product` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`brand_product`, '/', -1);
```

Output:

```
| brand_product | brand | product |
+---------------+-------+---------+
| one/two       | one   | two     |
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index