# how to split values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am writting sql script for the first time and i want to seperate a value that contains two user id's which looks like this

```
612831408762037_617540318291146
```

i want to separate these two so i have a 
user_id = `612831408762037` and post_id = `617540318291146` any ideas on how i shuld approch this?

thanks in advance

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/mysql-split-value-from-one-field-to-two

Comment: @user3659384, Please accept the answer which worked for you, it will be easy for other people who refers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
declare @var nvarchar(100)='612831408762037_617540318291146';

select 
    LEFT(@var, charindex('_',@var)-1), 
    RIGHT(@var, charindex('_',REVERSE(@var))-1)
```

Comment: will it work for this input 612831408762037_617540318291146234234234234 ?

Comment: @rinuthomaz Yeah... It won't work! I've updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a substr('value', start, length) for each portion that you want displayed. The substr function extracts and returns a specific segment from a string or value.

- You probably could achieve this by using a weird concat statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
DECLARE @document varchar(400);
DECLARE @FIRST int;

SELECT @document = '612831408762037_617540318291146234234234234';
SET @FIRST = (SELECT CHARINDEX('_', @document, 1));
SELECT rightSide = SUBSTRING(@document, 0,@FIRST), leftSide = SUBSTRING(@document, @FIRST+1, LEN(@document));
```