# Get values from today using specific php date timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Hello today I coded a system where each user login was recorded and inserted into a database using PDO for MySQL, and I logged each of these logins with a date using the below PHP code and instered each value into my MySQL database table called user_logins. I logged the logins with the date string below...

```
date("D dS F H:i:s")
```

That outputs "Sat 12th September 20:59:33" (for example), but what I am trying to do is get all of the values from user_logins table but only get them if they have happened today. So basically I want to turn the system I current have (displaying all recent logins) to only showing todays logins that have happened today?

Please don't sned me to another question, because them questions use a different `date()` method to me, and most questions I have already checked and are unsuccessful.

Comment: What datatype are you using for the last login field?

Comment: A varchar, using the date() in php as shown in the question.

Comment: Use the correct datatype. It's not a string: it's a date. Date data types allow for easy comparisons with other dates in queries, eg: "select * from user_logins where last_login > date_sub( now(), date_interval('24 hours'))". (From memory, possible typos)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change field type for the date, and make it `datetime`, using `2015-09-13 12:12:12` format.

Then you will have today's activity data by adding to WHERE clause

```
WHERE date(date_field) = CURDATE()
```

While to display your data you have to format it either in SELECT using [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) or in PHP, by using strtotime() AND date() frunctions.

This is how databases work, and sooner you learn it, the more time you'll save.

Comment: How can I format "2015-09-13 12:12:12" to how date("D dS F H:i:s") displays?

Answer (score -1):

You can split the date field into sub strings and then compare those day and month field. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two) to see how to split a string in mysql.