# I have values (abc,123,aed,ghi) and i want to split values individual in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have values 
`[abc,123,aed,ghi]` 
and i want to split values individual in mysql.
result should be like this

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
  abc    123    aed      ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

Relational database and non-atomic data is poor design . But you can use:

```
SELECT ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN N = 1 THEN sub.val END) AS Column1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN N = 2 THEN sub.val END) AS Column2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN N = 3 THEN sub.val END) AS Column3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN N = 4 THEN sub.val END) AS Column4
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.HashTag, ',', n.n), ',', -1) AS val, N
  FROM (SELECT ID, Substring(my_csv_column, 2, LENGTH(my_csv_column) - 2) AS HashTag FROM my_non_normalized_table) AS t 
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
  ) n
   WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.HashTag) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.HashTag, ',', '')))
) sub
GROUP BY ID;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/143d4/5/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ ID  ║ Column1  ║ Column2  ║ Column3  ║ Column4 ║
╠═════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║  1  ║ abc      ║ 123      ║ aed      ║ ghi     ║
║  2  ║ efg      ║ cde      ║ (null)   ║ (null)  ║
╚═════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

You should read about data normalization and `1NF`.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately MySQL does not feature a split string function. However
>   you can create a [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) for this, such as the one
>   described in the following article:
>
> - [MySQL Split String Function](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) by Federico Cargnelutti
>
> With that function, you would be able to build your query as follows:

```
 SELECT SPLIT_STR(fieldName, ',', 1) as abc,
      SPLIT_STR(fieldName, ',', 2) as 123,
      SPLIT_STR(fieldName, ',', 3) as aed,
      SPLIT_STR(fieldName, ',', 4) as ghi,
 FROM   YourTable;
```

[Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two/2696901#2696901)