# SQL-Order Strings containing numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following values in my table:

```
a 3
a 5
a 7
aa 5
a 10
b 5
```

With the ORDER BY command I get the following:

```
a 10
a 3
a 5
a 7
aa 5
b 5
```

I want the following result:

```
a 3
a 5
a 7
aa 5
a 10
b 5
```

Any ideas how I can solve it in my SQL query?

Comment: I don't understand the criteria

Comment: The problem is the data is in one column.

Comment: Fix that. Figure out the ordering criteria. Then get back to us.

Comment: What's the order of this sorting? say it in word not in some sample random  output.

Comment: You'll not be able to do that with the data at hand, you'll need to maintain a sort key column for something like this to be pratical.

Comment: you can split the column using something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two) however like what @Strawberry said, you are storing 2 things in a single column. if you fix that, you don't need to use splitting functions which may cause performance issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With a question like this it's helpful to give a little of the back story. What do these column values represent?  Why does `aa 5` come between `a 7` and `a 10` in your desired result? Is the number always preceded by a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substring_index()` to split data when order:

```
SELECT
    col1
FROM
    table1 t
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' ', 1),
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' ', 2),' ',- 1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

However `aa` will become after all `a` as your desired ordering logic is contradicting with data values in both 'columns', one of them must be leading. This query returns:

```
a 3
a 5
a 7
a 10
aa 5
b 5
```