# ORDER BY ASC not taking effect properly on String containing number

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL Workbench as IDE for creating my tables. I have created a stored procedure to show all rows of `level` column and attempted to order the result set in ascending order. `level` column is a varchar column.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllYearLevels`()
BEGIN
    SELECT `level` FROM yearlevel ORDER BY `level` ASC;
END
```

But when I perform a `CALL` to the getAllYearLevels procedure, it return the result with Grade 10 as second row instead of Grade 2.

```
call enrollmentdb.getAllYearLevels();
```

[image]

I know this is very simple to most but I just have no idea how to correct this. I used the correct syntax for ordering the result set. I thought maybe casting the `varchar` value is needed but I don't know how to break it apart. Or maybe, casting isn't necessary.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: the result is correct. is alphabetic . you can test **ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(level,' ',-1)+0 ASC** to get your wanted result

Comment: @Bernd Buffen Thanks a lot. I haven't used the SUBSTRING_INDEX(x,x,n)+0 before but this should add to my knowledge. I'll research more on this. I appreciate it. This solved my problem.

Comment: a little remark: this is verytime a FULL TABLE SCAN. if you have huge table it is better to change the table and add a virtual perstant field which can automatic generate the number and you can also create an index on this field. inform me if you want more infos about that

Comment: Does the virtual field act like a primary key? The year levels I need to include is from Grade 1 - 12 only. Can you give a short example of implementing it. I googled it but I'm not sure if the example here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/ applies. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL-Order Strings containing numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574965/sql-order-strings-containing-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a little sample of use SUBSTRING_INDEX and VIRTUAL COLUMN

Sample: show sorted rows of a small table

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT * FROM l ORDER BY substring_index(LEVEL,' ',-1)+0;
+----+----------+
| id | level    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Grade 1  |
|  3 | Grade 2  |
|  2 | Grade 10 |
+----+----------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Show table structure

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> show create table l;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| l     | CREATE TABLE `l` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `level` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Add a virtual persistent column:

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> ALTER TABLE l ADD level_int INT AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(`level`,' ',-1)) PERSISTENT;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (1.90 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Add new rows:

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> insert into l (level) VALUES ('Grade 23'),('Grade 132');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Show all rows andd see the field `level_int`:

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT * FROM l ORDER BY substring_index(LEVEL,' ',-1)+0;
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | level     | level_int |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Grade 1   |         1 |
|  3 | Grade 2   |         2 |
|  2 | Grade 10  |        10 |
|  4 | Grade 23  |        23 |
|  5 | Grade 132 |       132 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now you can add a index and query on the new column:

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> alter table l add index idx_level_int (level_int);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.93 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate the examples. It's very easy to follow and understand. This will help me in future projects because I really spend time with my procedures and table definition. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing level to contain only numbers and adding the text "Grade" to the result. Then sorting on the new numeric column will give you the order you want.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'll take note of the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, probably the easiest way is to sort by length first and then by the value:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(`level`), `level
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Schema design flaw...  Don't store "Grade 1" in a string column, store "1" in a numeric column.  When displaying, prepend with "Grade " if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that storing number is better after seeing the suggestions.