# In PHP, how to match id with names which names are in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP page and try to list my block categories with names instead of id's.
Here is my MariaDB output:

```
select id,name  from url_category_data;
+----+----------------------+
| id | name                 |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | adv                  |
|  2 | aggressive           |
|  3 | alcohol              |
|  4 | anonvpn              |
|  5 | automobile/bikes     |
|  6 | automobile/boats     |
|  7 | automobile/cars      |
|  8 | automobile/planes    |
|  9 | chat                 |
| 10 | costtraps            |
+----+----------------------+
```

I feed my block list by using those categories and stores as id.
Here is my block category list:

```
select policyid,category_list from url_category_block where status  = 1 ;
+----------+---------------+
| policyid | category_list |
+----------+---------------+
|        1 | 8,9,10        |
+----------+---------------+
```

When I try to use echo I can print out 8,9,10

```
<p> Result is:   
<?php
     if($result_block===true ||   $row_list = $result_block->fetch_assoc()){ 
       echo  $row_list["category_list"];}?>
</p>
```

Its output il like that:

> Result is: 8,9,10

But I want to display name  of these values, such as;

> Result is : 
> automobile/planes
>  chat
>  costtraps

To show my data, I show list as shortly. 
Actually there are nearly 150 category name and id. So, I have to automate this match process in PHP
I saw some answer this kind of question, but I am not very familiar with MySQL and PHP, so those answers not clear for me.
How can convert those id numbers to print to screen their names by using PHP?

Comment: You should normalize your database: Use a table to couple policy ID's to category ID's so that you can select what you need with a `JOIN`

Comment: Join the table with the `JOIN` command.

Comment: try to normalize the table by stoing it in diffrent table or get its result, and then again execute query to those ids only or u can use string function (custom) and use it. i am not sure about its performance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to normalise your `url_category_block` table and store each policy_id - category id pair in its own record. In this case a simple join on the field values will do the trick you are asking.

The quick solution is to use [find_in_set() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to join the 2 tables:

```
select *
from url_category_block a
inner join url_category_data b on find_in_set(b.id, a.category_list)>0
```

Comment: This is very userful really.

Answer (score 0):

Do what @jeroen sais in his comment.

Create a table (`url_category_block`), where you have a column `policyid` and a column `category_id`. For every policy and category combination you need you will have an entry. Then you can query along these lines:

```
SELECT url_category_data.name FROM url_category_block LEFT JOIN url_category_data ON url_category_block.category_id = url_category_data.id WHERE policyid = 1;
```

This query probably doesn't work right away. I didn't test it and every SQL syntax works a little bit different, but a quick Google search (for `sql`, `join`) should help you.

Comment: Is there any way in PHP to do this?

Comment: Sure! You could, e.g., use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to query your database. However, I've never worked with MariaDB so far.

Comment: they are exactly same , mariadb and mysql

Comment: `SELECT 
 url_category_data.name, 
 url_category_block.category_list 
FROM 
 url_category_data 
 INNER JOIN url_category_block ON url_category_data.id = url_category_block.category_list` show  a name and values. Such as:  automobile/planes as name and 8,9.10 as category_list. I think the comma between id's in category_list mess my data