# Similar To function in sql

Tags: sql

I am working on the query

```
(Select d_name from Direction where d_name  SIMILAR TO '(WEST|NORTH)%' )
this gives me the result as 
WEST 1
WEST 2
NORTH 2
WEST 
NORTH
```

But I want the result as

```
WEST
NORTH
```

with the same statement Similar To. Someone please modify the same query to get the 2nd result.
Thanks

Comment: which one sql or Mysql

Comment: Eh? You want to use similar to despite the fact that what you're actually looking for is exact matches? Isn't that a bit like seeking help with using a hammer to drive screws?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the query demand similar to. somewhere i need to select all the cols which is possible in similar to and not in like.

Comment: @mohan111 this is the sql query

Comment: Depending on the dbms used, I'd try replace_regexp instead, to remove the trailing numbers. Use IN on that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution

```
Select d_name 
from Direction 
where d_name  SIMILAR TO '(WEST|NORTH)'
```

Just remove **`%`** from the query.

Comment: but, for example, if 'WEST' value is not existing in any row of the table, but you only have 'WEST 1' kind of values, you will not have 'WEST' as results with your solution

Comment: @ddb: my understanding is that dhS _does_ want an "exact" match. But if a "wildcard" match is required, the wildcard would need to be added to each value: `SIMILAR TO '(WEST%|NORTH%)'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it's not anymore clear for me what he/she wants :) I thought I had a clear idea, but I don't now :) that's fine if he/she is happy of his/her own solution

Answer (score 3):

```
(select 'WEST' from Direction where d_name  SIMILAR TO 'WEST%')
UNION
(select 'NORTH' from Direction where d_name  SIMILAR TO 'NORTH%');
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I got the answer.

Comment: @dhS, you're welcome :) if you want you can accept my answer if solved you're question

Comment: I upvoted it ... can't accept as it is long way i need a shorter query.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, as it does not feature a split string function, you can create a [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) for this, such as the one described in the following article:

- [MySQL Split String Function](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) by Federico Cargnelutti

With that function, you would be able to build your query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SPLIT_STR(d_name, ' ', 1)
FROM Direction
WHERE d_name SIMILAR TO '(WEST|NORTH)%';
```

If you prefer not to use a user defined function and you do not mind the query to be a bit more verbose, you can also do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1)
FROM Direction
WHERE d_name SIMILAR TO '(WEST|NORTH)%';
```

Disclaimer: I based this new answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696901/3178454) solution