# Split mysql column word by word

Tags: mysql, asp.net

[click for image](http://domainalisveris.com/kampanya/soru.jpg)

hi 
I want to split mysql search result. I've added a sample image for the table. I want to select values word by word from adi field.

mysql:

```
select * from liste like %emlak%
```

Result:

> emlak1
>   emlak2
>   emlak3

I've used substring ets.. but it didn't work

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  sum((length(adi)-length(replace(adi,' ',''))+1)) as bosluk 
FROM liste2  
where adi like '%emlak%'
```

Comment: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two)

Answer (score 0):

maybe...

```
 SELECT liste2.*,
        sum((length(adi)-length(replace(adi,' ',''))+1)) as bosluk
   FROM liste2
  WHERE adi like '%emlak%'
```

add tablename or alias