# MYSQL - Split colon separated column values in to new columns

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this ,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cms` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `cms` (`id`, `cms`) VALUES
(1, 'cms:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.7'),
(2, 'cms:/o:netbsd:netbsd:1.0');
```

[image]

from which i need to split cms column values in to four additional columns , hence it has to be separated by colon.

i need output something like this

[image]

need query for this

Comment: MySQL isn't the best tool to be doing this.

Comment: then by which tool or script i should go for

Comment: Do you have access to Java?  It's super easy to explode a string using Java.  After this, bring the data into MySQL.  BTW, you're absolutely doing the right thing by normalizing your table data, but MySQL isn't so great in exploding strings.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2696901/2022457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It is a little bit dirty, but it works:

```
select source.*
, left(cms, FirstColon - 1) as CMS2
, mid(cms, FirstColon + 1, SecondColon - FirstColon -1) as Extension 
, mid(cms, SecondColon + 1, ThirdColon - SecondColon -1) as Product
, mid(cms, ThirdColon + 1, FourthColon - ThirdColon -1) as version
from (
    select a.*
    , locate(':', cms) 'FirstColon'
    , locate(':', cms, locate(':', cms) + 1) 'SecondColon'
    , locate(':', cms, locate(':', cms, locate(':', cms) + 1) + 1) 'ThirdColon'
    , locate(':', cms, locate(':', cms, locate(':', cms, locate(':', cms) + 1) + 1) + 1) 'FourthColon'
    from cms a
) source
;
```

But if you have Microsoft Excel installed, you can try [Excel Text To Column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) tool. Just export your raw data into Microsoft Excel format, and use that tool.