# Split MYSQL column into multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few million records in a mysql database with the following columns:
`company, address, url, phone, category`

Here is a sample row:
`Company123 - 123 Candyland St, New York, NY 12345 - http://urltothiscompany.com -  123-456-7890 - Bakery`

My question is about the address column. I'd like to split the rows up into separate address, city, state, and zip code columns:
`123 Candyland St - New York - NY - 12345`

However, some rows don't have a street, only city, state, and zip:
`New York, NY, 1235`

Is there a possible way to do that in mysql? I'm not sure where to begin since some rows don't have the address. Maybe count the characters from the end of the column?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would use your commas as separators and counting in reverse from the end of the string. The first section would be the zip, next the state, the city, and the street if exists. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two

Comment: my approach would be write a PHP script that grabs that column and use PHP's explode function on ` - `    You could also use the `isnumeric($zip)` to ensure its valid, or at least to different US ffrom Canada

Comment: If you are sure that only the street may be absent, then the solution proposed by CodeGodie is the right one. But if other fields too may be absent I suspect you need some sort of validation...

Comment: In your examples: the first one without comma (... NY 12345) the second has comma (..., NY , 1235) this is hard for data cut

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume your data is actually looking like following:

```
addr
=======================
street, City, State ZIP
```

And here is the SQL:

```
SELECT addr,
  substr(addr, 1, length(addr) - length(substring_index(addr, ',', -2))) street,
  substring_index(substring_index(addr, ',', -2), ',', 1) city,
  substr(trim(substring_index(addr, ',', -1)),1,2) state,
  substring_index(addr, ' ', -1) zip
FROM tab
```

[image]

OOPs there is an extra comma at street, this is a homework for you to fix :)

Comment: sorry for the delay, great answer!

Comment: Can I ask what GUI software/IDE this is?

Comment: http://topnew.net/sidu - SIDU DB GUI for MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite etc

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer for googlers as me.
Example splitting columns into 3. If you need 2 columns omit `new_column_name_2` inside requests.
Works for dimensions like `100x200x300` becomes `100 200 300`

1. Create new columns.

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name` ADD `new_column_name_1` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name` ADD `new_column_name_2` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name` ADD `new_column_name_3` VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT '';
```

2. Verify you're selecting correct stuff

```
SELECT `old_column_name`,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old_column_name`, 'x', 1) `new_column_name_1`,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old_column_name`, 'x', 2),'x',-1) `new_column_name_2`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old_column_name`, 'x', -1) `new_column_name_3`
FROM `your_table_name`;
```

3. Populate new columns

```
UPDATE `your_table_name` SET
`new_column_name_1` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old_column_name`, 'x', 1),
`new_column_name_2` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old_column_name`, 'x', 2),'x',-1),
`new_column_name_3` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old_column_name`, 'x', -1);
```