# count multiple occurence substrings in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm pulling data from Twitter API into my DB. There is a column 'hashtags' which stores a list of hashtags used in the tweet.

```
Table name: brexittweets
Column: hashtags varchar(500)
```

I want to count the number of hashtags. For example

```
                 Hashtags
Tweet1: ['EUref', 'Brexit', 'poll']

Tweet2: ['Brexit', 'Blair']

Tweet3: ['Brexit', 'Blair', 'EUref']
```

Result should be:

```
hashtag     count(hashtag)
Brexit      3
EUref       2
Blair       2
poll        1
```

What I was thinking of doing:
Tried to take substring between quotes ' ', but it occurs multiple times in the same row.

Tried using strpos to find instances of ' ', but it returns only the first instance.

Is there a way to do this with queries? I was thinking of trying out a procedure, but it gets complicated because I need to print these results on a web page using PHP.

Comment: `[ ]` are included in the string?

Comment: Yes. That's the way it's writing from Python, but I can get rid of them if they're too problematic.

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2696901/3270427

Comment: Thank you @McNets

Answer (score 1):

If only you've normalized your table such that each tag in a tweet gets stored on its own row, your problem would be solved easily by using `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the tags are separated by `', '`, you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
    hashtags, 
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(hashtags)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( hashtags , "', '", "") ) 
        ) / 4) + 1
     AS count
    from brexittweets
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fa21f/10/0)**.

Comment: Thank you. But does not work, because this just returns the number of hashtags in each record. I need count of each hashtag in the database. So for instance 'poll' should return a count of 1, which this query does not.