# Export stats from mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **mysql field** which has a **varchar value** with the following format:

```
option-value, option-value, option-value
```

Here are 2 example tuple values:

```
"desk-4, table-2, bed-5"
"desk-2, bed-3, table-8, mattress-10"
```

I want to have a php-mysql query which can **match** and **calculate** (sum) the **same products** with their values **from mutiple records**, so that the result would be:

```
desk 6
table 10
bed 8
mattress 10
```

Comment: Improved question format.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this function to split a string in MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696901/6441091

Then use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` on the result.