# How to get intersect value of two comma seperated string in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to find intersect value from two comma separated string in stored procedure.

String 1: **40,31,42,23,45** => System generated numbers

String 2: **30,23,24,31,25,32** => User selected numbers

I want to check that, do any of my numbers are present in system generated numbers.

Above value should return **23,31**.

I have solution that, i will loop through system generated numbers and will check one by one with my numbers using FIND_IN_SET, if present i will CONCATE that and will get required output.

But is there any shorter and optimized way to do this?

Comment: Check the answers posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two  maybe you will find a helpful approach.

Comment: Yes, it will be helpfull