# MySQL Not like query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to compare `table1` and `table2` with specified column as string and want to **return unmatched records** from `table1`.

It works great when I use other way just `'like'` and return matching result.

But I am really looking to get unmatched records.

Here is the sample tables

```
table 1
----------------------------------
No.     DesignID
1       c12345
2       c16
3       c20
```

```
    Table 2
    ----------------------
    No.    DesignOption
    1      Online-c12345-print
    2      Online-c16-proof
```

```
 $db->fetchallColumn(SELECT distinct(a.DesignID) FROM table1 as a, table2 as b where b.DesignOption 
    not like CONCAT('%', a.DesignID, '%'));
```

with join example

```
$db->fetchallColumn(SELECT distinct(a.DesignID) FROM table1 as a inner join 
table2 as b on b.DesignOption not like CONCAT('%', a.DesignID, '%'));
```

**Expected result: c20**

Instead I get all the records from table1

Comment: You need to `join` table1 to table2. Right now you're selecting everything from table1 (it's not currently restricted either by a where clause, or table2)

Comment: @RobbieToyota thanks for your quick response, I have tried some join queries but I get same result. I will add that in my question..

Comment: Looking at your update, it doesn't look like you've completed the join statement. Which column in table a, does b.DesignOption correspond to? You should have something like this: `SELECT [...] FROM table1 as a JOIN table2 as b ON b.DesignOption=a.CorrespondingColumn`.

Comment: Use a subquery using `where Like` as you stated above works, and then outer query `where not in subquery`. Also, wouldn't the expected results be `c19 and c20`?

Comment: @RobbieToyota.. I do not have matching indexes to use equal to operation, so I have used search pattern to get unmatched records. please refer the tables and give me your suggestion.

Comment: @WEI_DBA... sorry I have updated the table records.. should be c20.

Comment: Very good. But still look at my comment about subquery.

Comment: @WEI_DBA.. would you mind to give me some sample?

Comment: Gordon beat me to it... His was my next suggestion. Simpler and easier to code.

Comment: Will DesignOption allways follow a format of x-DesignID-y? If so, you should be able to use a string splitting function to `JOIN` without using a `NOT LIKE %x%`.

Comment: @Shawn.. Glad to know the several options,  would you mind to show up the option or reference link for string splitting functions. Thanks for your overview.

Comment: @Bagan I don't primarily work with MySQL, so I don't know if there's a better option in newer versions. This link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two) is older, but it should provide a good starting point. The first answer by Daniel Vassallo.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your query works, just use an outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.DesignID
FROM table1 a left join 
     table2 b 
     ON b.DesignOption like CONCAT('%', a.DesignID, '%')
WHERE b.DesignOption IS NULL;
```

Note that `DISTINCT` is not a function.  The SQL operator is `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Don't use parentheses -- unless you have a reason for doing so.

Comment: Your query having syntax error near  CONCAT('%', a.DesignID, '%'

Comment: A perfect Answer, Thank you Mr. Gordon

Answer (score 1):

You may try it this way

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.DesignID
FROM table2 a RIGHT JOIN 
table1 b 
ON a.DesignOption NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', b.DesignID, '%')
WHERE a.DesignOption IS NOT NULL;
```

Hope it will work

Comment: My personal belief is that `RIGHT JOIN`s were invented by aspirin companies to boost revenue. :-)  In most cases, a `RIGHT JOIN` can be rewritten as a `LEFT JOIN` to make more sense out of the data and produce slightly better query plans. Also, a `NOT LIKE` will be very heavy on the query optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

But if you want to see the subquery approach.

```
Select DesignID From Table1
Where DesignID not in (SELECT a.DesignID 
FROM table1 as a inner join 
table2 as b on b.DesignOption like CONCAT('%', a.DesignID, '%'))
```

Comment: Subquery works and is easy to understand, but it can be significantly less efficient in datasets larger than just a few thousand records in each table.

Comment: Thanks for your input.