# Wrap list elements in quotes, to be used in WHERE IN

Tags: mysql

Assuming I got a long list of comma-separated values:

```
one, two, three, .., hundred
```

and I need to use them in a `WHERE IN` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE IN (one, two, three, .., hundred)
```

then is there any way I can "tell" MySQL to wrap each of the values in quotes, or at least make it treat each of the values as strings? Without wrapping the values in quotes, the WHERE IN doesn't work.

**Note:** Surely there are plenty of ways to modify the list of values beforehand and then pass it to the query, but I'd like to know if there's a MySQL way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: No there isn't. You have to do it outside of mysql

Comment: Fair enough. One can use `FIND_IN_SET` as an alternative, as mentioned by Lalabhai Patel.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this query**

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE FIND_IN_SET(field_name,'one, two, three, hundred')
```

Comment: The answer is not in the context of `WHERE IN` but maybe the post needed an out-of-the-box one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with a Simple SQL query, however, you could do something like this:

- Create a user defined function that splits the String by comma (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two) SO answer) and wrap each token into double quotes
- Use `CONCAT` with parenthesis and store the resultant String into a variable (using `SET`)
- Use the value of the above variable in `IN` query (e.g. `WHERE value IN @val`)
- Execute all the queries in a batch or a procedure