# compair 2 strings in sql [first string contain 2nd string's substrings]

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

i am sharing a java code related to my question, by that  you can easily understand what i am exactly looking in SQL.

**Java code**

```
String s1 = "http://hdvidz.co/video/file/Naa-Peru-Meenakshi-%7C-11th?id=rj5e--8vQb4";
    String s2 = "Naa Peru Meenakshi";
    String splitStringS2[] = s2.split(" ");// using blank space to split
    int i = 0;
    for (String a : splitStringS2) {
        if (s1.contains(a)) {
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("break perform");
            i = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("value of i===  " + i);
```

i have 2 table ; table A has a column "link" that contain value "http://hdvidz.co/video/file/Naa-Peru-Meenakshi-%7C-11th?id=rj5e--8vQb4";
table B has a column "name" that contain value "Naa Peru Meenakshi"

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (`link` VARCHAR(255) );
insert into A values("http://hdvidz.co/video/file/Naa-Peru-Meenakshi-%7C-11th?id=rj5e--8vQb4");
CREATE TABLE `B`(`name` VARCHAR(255) );
insert into B values("Naa Peru Meenakshi");
```

now what exactly i want

1) pick a value from table B and split into substring and store in array **splitName**.

2) pick a value from table A & store in variable **url**

3) now checking substring (**splitName**) exist in variable **url**

4) if all substring found in **url** return count (substring match)  , else return 0

above java code is doing same thing.

Comment: choose any one of MySQL, java & sql-server which are different.

Comment: So the question here is what are we trying to achieve? Is it a code sample to display  My Name is Meenakshi

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please be specific and detailed about what you're trying to do in which language.

Comment: @Satya i have lot of data in two different tables, one table contain String s1 and second table contain string s2, and we want to check 1st string belonging to 2 string  or not , this is a example for single test here we will perform it with multiple data

Comment: @E.Villiger , i am looking same thing in SQL, i wrote java code to understand what exactly i want in SQL

Comment: I don't think SQL is the right tool for this. Sounds more like it should be a PHP question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure. 
I haven't used MySQL in a while, but I'm fairly sure it doesn't support a split function. You can write a user-defined procedure as done in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two).

I think you can also use LOCATE to find the position of a sub-string inside a string.
UPDATE: Check the second answer in the link.

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server Try this below query :

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
 SELECT
  1 as Seq  ,
  COL ,
  Val = COL
  FROM T1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Seq = Seq+1,
  COL = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(COL,CHARINDEX(' ',COL),LEN(COL))),
  Val = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(COL,1,CHARINDEX(' ',COL))))
  FROM CTE
    WHERE ISNULL(Val,'')<>''
)
SELECT
  Val = CASE WHEN ISNULL(Val,'')<>'' THEN Val
    ELSE Col END
  FROM CTE
    WHERE Seq > 1
```

I'm assuming that you have these values in a column **COL** on table **T1**. You can replace the first select query

```
SELECT
  1 as Seq  ,
  COL ,
  Val = COL
  FROM T1
```

With your desired input.

For the below input

[image: Input]

The output is as below

[image: Result]

Check The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86b93/6) here

Comment: your answer looking like split a string in sub string ; its very far far from my question.

Comment: Then Please add some more details to the question. You have only mentioned that "you can easily identify my requirement" from the code and this is what I understood