# How to split data from one column to another columns in same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an column name phone1 which contain phone#

```
0345123456,032145678
0345221123,032443332
0347886543,038875532
0345776767
```

I have to seperate Phone# after ","  in another column name phone 2
for example

```
0345123456 in  phone1 
032145678  in  phone2
```

Comment: Do not store values as CSV. Learn about normalization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two)

Answer (score 0):

from sample data it seems to me you need below

```
   select
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(phone#, ",", -1) as phone1,        
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(phone#, ",", 1) as phone2 from table1
    where phone# like '%,%'
    union all
    select phone# as phone1,  '' as phone2  fraon table1  
     where phone# not like '%,%'
```

Answer (score -1):

using substring_index you can splix strings based on delimiter

```
substring_index(`#phone`,',',1) as phone1,substring_index(`#phone`,',',-1) as phone2
```

this is aplicable only if u know how much to be delimited

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  SELECT concat(Substring(phone, 1, Locate(',', phone) - 1),' in phone1') AS 
            phone1, 
           concat(Substring(phone, Locate(',', phone) + 1),' in phone2')   AS phone2
    FROM   tablename where phone not like '%,%'
```

Comment: what is the result of your query if there is no `,` in the value? like the last line of op's sample data?

Comment: yes, i need to filtered it, thank u. But one question to u - do you think giving downvote is more suitable than commenting about someone's mistake