# seperate values in in a cell in mysql

Tags: mysql, opencart, cell

I have the following table and I want to seperate the values in the cell with a select query.

The values in the cell are between `"` and are the separation of the column I want to be where `:`

The table is like this:

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
|john|data3w43|data2    |"{""4"":""6935593"",""6756756"":"""",""1"":""hfghh"",""3"":""89899"",""5"":"""",""2"":""2""}"|
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
|joh3|data3423|data102  |"{""43"":""69741354534593"",""62"":""34"",""1"":"""",""3"":""hgfhg"",""5"":"""",""2"":""2""}"|
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
|j3hn|data3434|data32   |"{""4"":""6974135593"",""6"":"""",""1"":""hfgh"",""3"":""hfgh"",""5"":""hfgh6"",""2"":""2""}"|
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I want to have a table with a select like this:

```
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
|john|data3w43|data2    |4 |6935593       |6756756|  |1|hfghh|3|89899|5 |     |2|2|
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
|joh3|data3423|data102  |43|69741354534593|62     |34|1|     |3|hgfhg|5 |     |2|2|
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
|j3hn|data3434|data32   |4 |6974135593    |6      |  |1|hfgh |3|hfgh |5 |hfgh6|2|2|
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can do that using split and replace functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two.
From the data you shown us you can split with the "|" caracter, split it again with the ":" caracter. Finally you need to clean the remaining data from unwating caracters: " , { , and so on... hope it helps

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply but I can not use split because I don't know the size of the data inside the "