# How to sum MySQL varchar field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Varchar field for total_amount, the field has something like 1+1+1

I need to sum this column.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an ability to evaluate arithmetic expressions.

Comment: you need to split the string with '+' and calculate the sum

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A, but that isn't obvious how to do, is it?

Comment: How to split '+' would you explain. @JIJOMONK.A

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two

Comment: Are you allowed to create temp tables and procedures in the database?

Comment: Yes Its possible  @Joakim Danielso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution that is based on a function for splitting a string that I've found on several places on the net so I am not sure who to credit for and a function that uses the split function to calculate a total

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `CalcTotal`(input VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE pos int;
  DECLARE result int;
  DECLARE value_str VARCHAR(255);

  SET pos = 1;
  SET result = 0;
  SET value_str = '0';

  WHILE value_str <> '' DO
    SET value_str = SPLIT_STR(input, '+', pos);
    IF value_str <> '' THEN
      SET result = result + value_str;
      SET pos = pos + 1;
    END IF;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN (result);
END$$

CREATE FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR`(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT) RETURNS varchar(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
         LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1), delim, '');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

To use it do something like

```
SELECT CalcTotal(total_amount) 
FROM some_table
```

Note that I have set the max length of the varchar to 255 and assumed only integer values but this can of course be modified

Comment: Thanks for your answer its solved my problem. @Joakim