# Splitting up a name in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How can I split up a name before/after the and insert into a new table with other attributes that both artists have?
I prefer to split and keep in same table.My `Artists` table contains `Artist`, `PageURL`, `AlbumURL`.

**My table results:**

[image]

Comment: Please take a loot at MySql documentation describing string functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html. I think SUBSTRING_INDEX function should work for you.

Comment: I already tried that with `code`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Artist, 'and' , 2)
from Artists`code`
 and I don't get the results

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following split up query to get name seperated :

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Artist,' And ',1) as name1, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(Artist,' And ',-1) as name2 ,PageURL,AlbumURL 
  From Artists
```

Add this select statement into an insert query for the new table

```
    INSERT INTO Artists2
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Artist,' And ',1) as name1, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(Artist,' And ',-1) as name2 ,PageURL,AlbumURL 
    From Artists
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help...

```
DECLARE @Vlaue VARCHAR(100) = 'ABCD and EFGH'

DECLARE @index INT = (SELECT CHARINDEX('and', @Vlaue))
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Vlaue,1,@index-1) as FirstPart, SUBSTRING(@Vlaue,@index+3,LEN(@Vlaue) - @index) SecondPart
--SELECT SUBSTRING(@Vlaue,1,CHARINDEX('and', @Vlaue)-1) as FirstPart, SUBSTRING(@Vlaue,CHARINDEX('and', @Vlaue)+3,LEN(@Vlaue) - @index) SecondPart
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below query will split two names but if you have more than two names in Artist column then you have to create MySQL function.

```
select
    *,
    substring_index(Artist, ' And ', 1) as FirstArtist,
    substring_index(Artist, ' And ', -1)  as LastArtist
from Artists;
```

Check this post-
[Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two)

Do you want below stuff? please confirm.

Assume current data -

```
Artist
Metz And Trix
Djo2 And DJ Srk
```

Required data in same table -

```
Artist
Metz
Trix
Djo2
DJ Srk
```

Solution-
You need to insert second artists then update the first artists records. Please execute insert command first then update command. Please test before applying to production.

```
insert into Artists (Artist, PageURL, AlbumURL)
select substring_index(Artist, ' And ', -1), PageURL, AlbumURL
from tmp.Artists;

update Artists
set Artist = substring_index(Artist, ' And ', 1)
where Artist like '% And %'
```

Comment: I do have two artists in the same column with and in between them.

Comment: I got this to work with code `code`SELECT SPLIT_STR(Artist, ' And ', 1) as Artist1,
       SPLIT_STR(Artist, ' And ', 2) as Artist2
FROM   Artists
WHERE Artist Like '% And %' `code`. Can you please tell me how can I insert the same attributes that I already have and insert both Artists into Artists table?

Comment: If you already have data in your table and you want to split and save data into other columns then you need `update` command instead of `insert` command. please provide your table column structure.

Comment: I would do update but the only problem is I want to make another row for Artist2 the one after the and and insert into Artists Table. I only know how to do update if there is an error in the name but can you show me how to split up string and copy attributes?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please confirm that I am assuming in correct way.

Comment: yes, that is what I want. And the other thing is I want to copy the attributes of Metz And Trix which are PageURL, AlbumURL to Metz , PageURL, AlbumURL, and Trix PageURL, AlbumURL

Comment: Added solution to answer.